# Django profile attributes not shown in template

Tags: django, django-profiles

For some reason I can not get custom user profiles to work.
The following is what I tried:

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    program = models.ForeignKey("Program")
    book_date = models.DateField('book date')
    def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s" % (self.user)
#User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

views.py:

```
def showProgram(request,program_id):
    program = Program.objects.get(id=program_id)
    t = loader.get_template('controltool2/showProgram.html')
    c = Context({'program':program,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

showProgram.html:

```
<h1>Your Program: {{ request.user.get_profile.program }}</h1>
```

I also tried with

```
{{ user.get_profile.program }}
```

or

```
{{ request.user.get_profile().program }}
```

or using the lambda function (see #comment in models.py)

Am I missing something?
Thanks for any hint!

Ah yes, and I did

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'mymodelname.UserProfile'
```

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: have you included django.core.context_processors.request in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS ?

Comment: Thanks Glyn, it worked even w/o after using RequestContext (see answer below). Probably it's in the default list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `RequestContext` in place of `Context`:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
###
###
c = RequestContext(request, {'program': program})
```

Also, you must have `django.core.context_processors.request` in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.